# how to Add form date to html table

Tags: php

Hi I want to send form data to a php confirmation page. The confirmation page should contain details of registrants.New registrants' detail should be added to the previously registered ones. Here is what I have done, but instead of adding new info to the table, it replaces it. I am new to php and I need advice on how to get round it. it should look like this after submitting:

```
--------------------------
Registration Conformation |
---------------------------------------------
First name    |Last name     |Email         |
---------------------------------------------
Jack          |Fams          |mail@time.com |
---------------------------------------------
Matthew       |Bills         |mail@time.com |
---------------------------------------------
Judith        |Kamps         |mail@time.com |
---------------------------------------------




     <html>
        <head>
        <title>Registration form
        </title>
        <style type="text/css">

        .button{

            box-shadow: 10px 10px 5px #888888;
            padding: 5px;
            width: 90%;
        }

        .div{

            border: 2px solid black;
            width: 28%;
            margin: auto;
            margin-top: 15%;
            padding: 10px;
            font-family: Comic Sans;
            text-align: center;
        }

        h1{
            text-align: center;
            font-family: "Comic Sans", "Comic Sans MS", cursive;
            font-weight: bold;
        }

        table.set{

            text-align: center;
            margin-left: auto;
            margin-right: auto;
            width: 60%;
        }

        td{
            text-align: left;
            font-family: "Comic Sans", "Comic Sans MS", cursive;
            font-weight: bold;
        }

        </style>
        </head>
        <body>
            <div class="div">
            <form method="POST" action="registry.php">
            <h1>NewsLetter-Registration</h1>
            <table class="set">
            <tr><td>First Name:</td><td><input type='text' name='fname' size="25" /></td></tr>
            <tr><td>Last Name:</td><td><input type='text' name='lname' size="25"/></td></tr>
            <tr><td>E-mail:</td><td><input type='text' name='email' size="25"/></td></tr>
            <tr><td></td><td><input class="button" type="submit" name="register" value="Register"></td></tr>
            </table>
            </form>
            </div>
        </body>
    </html>


registry.php

<html>
    <head>
    <title>Registration form
    </title>
    <style type="text/css">

    .button{

        box-shadow: 10px 10px 5px #888888;
        padding: 5px;
        width: 90%;
    }

    .div{
        width: 60%;
        margin: auto;
        margin-top: 15%;
        padding: 10px;
        font-family: Comic Sans;
        text-align: center;
    }

    h1{
        text-align: left;
        font-family: "Comic Sans", "Comic Sans MS", cursive;
        font-weight: bold;
    }

    table.set{

        text-align: center;
        margin-left: auto;
        margin-right: auto;
        width: 60%;
        border-collapse: collapse;
        border: 2px solid black;
    }

    td{
        text-align: left;
        font-family: "Comic Sans", "Comic Sans MS", cursive;
        font-weight: bold;
    }

    </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="div">
        <table class="set" border="1">
        <tr><td colspan="3"><h1>NewsLetter-Registry</h1></td></tr>
        <tr><td>First Name:</td><td>Last Name:</td><td>E-mail</td></tr>
            <tr><td><?php echo $_POST["fname"]; ?></td><td><?php echo $_POST["lname"]; ?></td><td><?php echo $_POST["email"]; ?></td></tr>;
        </table>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: It looks like you need to use a database to store the previous registrants. And each time you load the confirmation page you would have an SQL query to fetch all the currently registered people.

Comment: Thanks a lot JREAM, is there no other way to do this without using a database?

Answer (score 0):

**Problem**

At the moment you're simply sending the form data to a new page and printing it inside the table. It is not stored anywhere.

As you want to achieve this without database, you can use a csv or json file which we cann "data file"

1. Submit form to registry.php
2. Append new entry to data file
3. Load data file and using "while" or "loop" print the data into the table

A quick example for a simple way (not best way) - for large data, appending or database will be your best solution.

**registry.php**

```
<?php
    $datafile = "data.json";
    $data = json_decode(file_get_contents($datafile),1); //make sure to create data.json empty file first

    if(isset($_POST['fname'])){
        $data[] = array(
            'fname' => $_POST['fname'],
            'lname' => $_POST['lname'],
            'email' => $_POST['email']
        );

       file_put_contents($datafile, json_encode($data,1)); //save new file
    }
?>
```

You can then print the table thus:

```
    <table class="set" border="1">
    <tr><td colspan="3"><h1>NewsLetter-Registry</h1></td></tr>
    <tr><td>First Name:</td><td>Last Name:</td><td>E-mail</td></tr>
    <?php
    foreach($data as $i=>$entry){
    <tr><td><?php echo $entry["fname"]; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $entry["lname"]; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $entry["email"]; ?></td></tr>
    } ?>
    </table>
```

This is a basic example and untested so if there's errors let me know and I'll update the code. You'll need to